# ng-Show not working when compiling html template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a function to load html using ajax and compiling it dynamically and it worked fine using angular 1.2*

after switching to angular 1.3.* / 1.4.0  the ng-show directive stopped responding although when I inspect the scope, i see that the data is changing.

I have also noticed that if I compile using the rootscope , the ng-show works but i don't have my data as the new scope is not a child of the existing scope.

this is the code I'm using

```
$scope.ticket = {showAdvance:false};
$scope.afterAjaxFinished = function(htmlContent, container)
{
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp']);
    $injector.invoke(function ($compile,$rootScope)
    {
        if ($scope)
        {
            container.appendChild($compile(htmlContent)($scope)[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            container.appendChild($compile(htmlContent)($rootScope)[0]);          
        }
    });
};
```

and the following HTML within the template ( htmlContent )

```
<div data-ng-click="ticket.showAdvance=!ticket.showAdvance">Toggle showing ticket</div>
<div data-ng-show="ticket.showAdvance">Showing Ticket</div>
```

**htmlContent** is my dynamic template

**container** is the element that is already in the dom

help anyone ?

Comment: You better share the html part with `ng-show`

Comment: And definition of the property bound in the `ng-show` expression

Comment: `if (scope)` is this correct?  '$scope' vs 'scope'. (I can see how it could be correct but since it's impossible to know within the context I just want to make sure it's not a typo.)

Comment: The scope was a typo as I copy pasted a huge code and cut the relevant part.